# How to check all values in columns efficiently using Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm wondering how to make dynamic filter given unknown columns in Spark.

For example, the dataframe is like below:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| colA  | colB  |  colC |  colD |  colE |  colF | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   |
| Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   |
| Red   | Blue  | Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   |
| Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   |
| Red   | Red   | Red   | Red   | Blue  | Red   |
| Red   | Red   | White | Red   | Red   | Red   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The columns can only be known at runtime, meaning it can have colG, H .. 
I need to check if the whole column's value is Red, then get a count, in above case is 3 as colA, colD and ColF columns are all Red.

What I am doing is something like below, and it is SLOW..

```
   val allColumns = df.columns
   df.foldLeft(allColumns) {

      (df, column) =>
        val tmpDf = df.filter(df(column) === "Red")
        if (tmpDf.rdd.isEmpty) {
          count += 1
        }
        df
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a better way. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got N RDD scans where N is number of columns. You can scan all of them at once and reducing in parallel. For example this way:

```
df.reduce((a, r) => Row.fromSeq(a.toSeq.zip(r.toSeq)
    .map { case (a, r) => 
          if (a == "Red" && r == "Red") "Red" else "Not" 
    }
))

res11: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [Red,Not,Not]
```

This code will do one RDD scan, and then iterated Row columns inside reduce.  Row.toSeq get Seq from Row. fromSeq restore Row to return the same object.

Edit: for count just add: `.toSeq.filter(_ == "Red").size`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do `df.filter` + `df.count` using only DataFrame API?

```
val filter_expr = df.columns.map(c => col(c) === lit("Red")).reduce(_ and _)

val count = df.filter(filter_expr).count

//count: Long = 3
```